# Reading National Elevation Dataset (ArcGrid/GridFloat/IMG) with Python only tools?

Tags: python, elevation, esri-grid-format

I've found high precision elevation (1/3 - 1/9 arcsecond resolution) data from the National Elevation Dataset provided by the USGS. It comes int IMG, Arcgrid, and GridFloat formats. I know ArcGrid corresponds to a paid software package, but I'm trying to stick to using freely available tools.

I have GPS data that I'm trying to correlate with ground level.

Are there any python libraries which will let me transform gps data into altitude using a datafile in IMG, ArcGrid, or GridFloat formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working with the IMG file directly in python is straightforward with the GDAL bindings.  For example, you can read the data directly into a NumPy array:

```
from osgeo import gdal
geo = gdal.Open('imgn36w100_11.img')
arr = geo.ReadAsArray()
print repr(arr)
array([[ 744.31896973,  743.68762207,  743.1116333 , ...,  550.42498779,
         553.77813721,  556.18640137],
       [ 744.22955322,  743.66082764,  743.05273438, ...,  552.05706787,
         554.81365967,  557.55877686],
       [ 744.0133667 ,  743.49041748,  743.00061035, ...,  553.0123291 ,
         555.78076172,  558.01312256],
       ...,
       [ 568.70880127,  567.33666992,  566.56170654, ...,  447.68035889,
         447.68804932,  447.65426636],
       [ 568.01116943,  566.95739746,  564.23382568, ...,  447.6696167 ,
         447.71224976,  447.62734985],
       [ 565.62896729,  562.65325928,  560.78759766, ...,  447.67129517,
         447.67529297,  447.65179443]], dtype=float32)
```

For a more complete example of plotting IMG format data, see [this script](https://github.com/kjordahl/SciPy2013/blob/master/examples/kauai.py) which generated the image below.  For your transformation of GPS data into altitude, you'll have to sample the resulting NumPy array.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The National Map Viewer used to use a different software platform, which made it possible to convert the data to GeoTIFF after selection of tiles. Some regional data provider do prefer GeoTIFF as well. But that may be of no help to you.

However, the good news is that `gdal` is able to work with all three of these formats. ArcGrid is an ESRI binary format, GridFloat USGS's DEM data format and IMG proprietary to Erdas, who make the Imagine software. I would probably download either the ArcGrid or the IMG format and convert to GeoTIFF: The USGS themselves have a bundle of conversion scripts based on `gdal` [for download](http://nationalmap.gov/data_delivery/ned.html) (direct [link to ZIP file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prd-tnm/RasterConversionScripts/USGS_Raster_Conversion_Scripts.zip)). You should find the resources you need there.

Comment: Thanks for the link and mentioning gdal, it looks very useful

Answer (score 0):

[Kelsey's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71176/115) didn't work at first for me because the .img file used -inf as the value for void space.

I solved this by adding the line:

```
topo[topo<-1000] = 0
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question, it probably should be an edit to the accepted answer